# Photo cataloging software which can group photos in stacks similar to Lightroom

Tags: software-recommendation

I use *Lightroom* to catalog my photos using extensively [its stacking feature](https://sleeklens.com/adobe-lightroom-image-stacking/) (particularly for grouping the bracketed exposures and the HDR result together).

I'd like to migrate to some other photo cataloging software (for Mac), but it needs to have the stacks feature. I couldn't any so far: Apple's *Aperture* had it, but this is yesterday. *Mylio* doesn't have it, neither has *Capture One*.

Which photo cataloging software can group photos in stacks similar to Lightroom

Comment: Why are you looking to move away from LR while it has the feature you want?

Comment: The obvious reason would be to no longer have to *rent* it.

Comment: You are probably going to be considered off topic here.  SE groups keep punting software recommendations off into their own group, where they languish because not enough photo experts read SR.se.  I'm upvoting you here, because I think that photo related software should be discussed in this SE even if such information has a relatively short relevancy lifespan.

Comment: Try also asking on dpreview.com and reddit.com/askphotography

Comment: @Tetsujin Just being Adobe may be reason enough ;-)

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke I don't manage to like LR's look 'n feel: It's rather un-Mac-ish, feels IMHO cumbersome and sluggish. Back in the days I loved Apple's Aperture (which wasn't the fastest, but not too bad).

Comment: @SherwoodBotsford Thanks for the detailed meta info. Shame that recommendation questions are discouraged - and strange that then a  `software-recommendation` tag exists!

Comment: [This forum post](http://forums.camerabits.com/index.php?topic=12349.0) suggests the stacking feature is patented by Adobe and Apple and is therefore unlikely to show up in other software. Haven't verified this though.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke Interesting! Thus _might_ explain that I couldn't find any other application with this feature

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible workaround:

Many packages have a smart album feature, which is just the result of a search that is stored.

Many also have a way to choose one image to be shown as the album 'cover'

So you use a set of keywords of the form ST007 and you give all the selected pix that keyword.  You have a separate folder called Stacks that is only smart albums labeled with ST* keywords.

I don't think this is workable unless you can set up some macros to do it.

Comment: Creative answer! But does seem really practical to me, because when you switch from  an image in the smart album with the "picks' to the full library you probably loose context and have to find again the image you looked at.